# ASP.NET Download Image file from URL with querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to download an image from a URL. The URL has a security key appended to the end and I keep getting the following error:
System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path

I'm not sure the correct syntax to use for this. Here is my code below.

```
string remoteImgPath = "https://mysource.com/2012-08-01/Images/front/y/123456789.jpg?api_key=RgTYUSXe7783u45sRR";
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(remoteImgPath);
string localPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "LocalFolder\\Images\\Originals\\" + fileName;
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(remoteImgPath, localPath);
return localPath;
```

Comment: I don't think `Path.GetFileName` does what you think it does.

Comment: it returns the file name and extension of the specified path string
Ah, I wasn't even looking there. I need to split the file so it's not grabbing the query string in the local file path.

Comment: Brian, that was it. Man, I had when you miss something so obvious. You want to put your answer and I'll mark it?

Comment: I just added an answer for you...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that this is what you're looking for:

```
string remoteImgPath = "https://mysource.com/2012-08-01/Images/front/y/123456789.jpg?api_key=RgTYUSXe7783u45sRR";
Uri remoteImgPathUri = new Uri(remoteImgPath);
string remoteImgPathWithoutQuery = remoteImgPathUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(remoteImgPathWithoutQuery);
string localPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "LocalFolder\\Images\\Originals\\" + fileName;
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(remoteImgPath, localPath);
return localPath;
```

Comment: In my case, I am getting exception saying "The given path's format is not supported.". What to do ?